# How many attunement slots do the Teeth of Dahlver-Nar use?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, attunement, artifacts

How many attunement slots do the Teeth of Dahlver-Nar use?
Is it one attunement slot per tooth, or one attunement slot for all of the teeth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be 1 attunement slot for the set.

I take this to be the case due the wording in the *Implanting Teeth* section which says:

> To implant the tooth, you place it in your mouth, whereupon one of your own teeth falls out, and the drawn tooth takes its place, resizing to fit in your mouth. Once the tooth is implanted, you gain the effect noted in the Implanted Effect column. The tooth can't be removed while **you are attuned to the teeth, and you can't voluntarily end your attunement to them.**

It refers to plural teeth each time so clearly you aren't just attuning to a single tooth.

Answer (score 4):

### You are attuned to the teeth as a whole

The *Teeth of Dahlver-Nal* are a single magic item, an artefact, with the attunement property attached to the "Teeth". This is shown explicitly in the ***Implanting Teeth*** section of the artefacts description:

> **Implanting Teeth** [...] The tooth can't be removed while you are attuned to the teeth and you can't voluntarily end your attunement to them. [...]